# Library redefines NULL

Tags: c++, c, null, undefined, c-preprocessor

I'm working with a library that redefines NULL. It causes some problems with other parts of my program. I'm not sure what I can do about it. Any idea? My program's in C++, the library's in **C**.

```
#ifdef NULL
#undef NULL
#endif

/**
 * NULL define.
 */
#define NULL    ((void *) 0)
```

Oh, and it produces these errors:

```
Generic.h:67: error: default argument for parameter of type 'LCD::LCDBase*' has type 'void*'
Generic.cpp: In constructor 'LCD::Generic::Generic(std::string, Json::Value*, int, LCD::LCDBase*)':
Generic.cpp:44: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'QObject*'
Generic.cpp:44: error:   initializing argument 2 of 'LCD::LCDWrapper::LCDWrapper(LCD::LCDInterface*, QObject*)'
Generic.cpp: In member function 'void LCD::Generic::BuildLayouts()':
Generic.cpp:202: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'LCD::Widget*'
Generic.cpp: In member function 'void LCD::Generic::AddWidget(std::string, unsigned int, unsigned int, std::string)':
Generic.cpp:459: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'LCD::Widget*'
scons: *** [Generic.o] Error 1
```

Here's the first one:

```
Generic(std::string name, Json::Value *config, int type, LCDBase *lcd = NULL);
```

Edit: Ok, casting explicitly works, but how do I cast for a function pointer?

Comment: Have you tried undefinining NULL after including it?

Comment: I'm not sure what to redefine it to. I tried saving NULL in ORG_NULL and redefining NULL after including libvisual, but that didn't work.

Comment: Actually, I think I just need to cast NULL appropriately.

Comment: As a side note: Please have words with the library authors, if possible. There's no good reason they should have redefined NULL - it's defined already. If they REALLY needed their own constant, they should have named it something else, so it wouldn't interfere.

Comment: `#define ORG_NULL NULL` doesn't save anything, btw, the cpp isn't that simple :P.  You could use any valid definition of NULL, such as `0`; however, the best solution is still to get the library fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you rebuild the library without that define? That's what I'd try first. `NULL` is a pretty standard macro, and should be assumed to be defined everywhere.

Right now, your problem is that C++ doesn't allow automatic casts from `void *` to other pointer types like C does.

From [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/NULL/):

> In C++, NULL expands either to 0 or 0L.

If that doesn't work, just do a global replace in the library: `NULL` to `LIBDEFINEDNULL` or something. That way you'll keep the library code intact and avoid the macro collision.

Comment: I thought about that, but the library likely redefined it for an internal reason. That'll be the last thing I try. I'm going to try and cast NULL appropriately.

Comment: I chatted with someone on the lib's IRC channel. He's not sure why NULL was redefined. I went ahead and just removed it from the library, and it compiled fine.

Comment: Fascinating. That one belongs on the DailyWTF! Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 3):

Do you have access to that libraries source? If so, I think a search and replace on their code is in order. (Replace their NULL with LIBNAME_NULL or something similar.) If that's simply not an option then I would recommend using 0 in your code instead of NULL.

I'm curious, though: What problems is that causing? They're not changing the value of null, only the default casting.

Comment: In C you can implicitly cast from void* to all pointer types.  In C++ you can't.  Since the library defines it to ((void*)0) he's having problems with C++ code.

Comment: Ah, good point asveikau. I've been doing some C interfaces lately, so I'm kinda stuck in that mindset :)

Answer (score 3):

The most generic approach would be to wrap up the offending includes and *store* and *restore* the macros previous definition. This, however, is compiler-dependent.
This is how you could do it with VC:

```
#pragma push_macro("NULL")
#include <offendinglib.h>
#pragma pop_macro("NULL")
```

Alternatively, set the macro to what you need it to be afterwards:

```
#include <offendinglib.h>
#undef NULL
#define NULL 0
```

Answer (score 3):

One of your comments says you've considered redefining it yourself, but you don't know what to redefine it to.

A lot of implementations will define NULL like this:

```
#undef NULL

#ifdef __cplusplus
#define NULL 0
#else
#define NULL ((void*)0)
#endif
```

This is because in C, it makes sense to have it as a void pointer, because it's a pointer type that can be implicitly cast to other types.

C++ doesn't allow this (which is causing your problems), but using `0` instead of `NULL` works.

I think in all recent versions, GCC will actually define it to `__null`, which is a non-portable extension.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you do just need to cast appropriately:

```
Generic(std::string name, Json::Value *config, int type,
    LCDBase *lcd = (LCDBase *)NULL);
```

Comment: You are not supposed to be needing casts from `NULL` to `T*` in C++.

Comment: gf, but that library redefines NULL so it won't cast implicitly.

Comment: Bad idea.  Misses the point of the NULL macro.  If you write code that casts NULL, people will look at your code and think you're dumb.  :-)

Comment: If i am not mixing up anything: the library is in C and redefines in the headers, the problem seems to be resulting from includes from the C library into the C++ code.

Comment: Sounds like the library is "to blame", so fix the library. Don't mess up all your own code to "fix" the library's problem.